# In Redis, how can I guarantee fetching N number items from a list in multi-clients environment?

Tags: redis

Assume that there is a key K in Redis that is holding a list of values.

Many producer clients are adding elements to this list, one by one using LPUSH or RPUSH.

On the other hand, another set of consumer clients are popping elements from the list, though with certain restriction. Consumers will only attempt to pop N number of items, only if the list contains at least N number of items. This ensures that the consumer will hold N items in hand after finishing popping process

If the list contains fewer than N number of items, consumers shouldn't even attempt to pop elements from the list at all, because they won't have at least N items at the end.

If there is only 1 Consumer client, the client can simply run `LLEN` command to check if the list contains at least N items, and subtract N using LPOP/RPOP.

However, if there are many consumer clients, there can be a race condition and they can simultaneously pop items from the list, after reading `LLEN` >= N. So we might end up in a state where each consumer might pop fewer than N elements, and there is no item left in the list in Redis.

Using a separate locking system seems to be one way to tackle this issue, but I was curious if this type of operation can be done only using Redis commands, such as Multi/Exec/Watch etc.

I checked Multi/Exec approach and it seems that they do not support rollback. Also, all commands executed between Multi/Exec transaction will return 'QUEUED' so I won't be able to know if N number of LPOP that I will be executing in the transaction will all return elements or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all you need is an atomic way to check on list length and pop conditionally.

This is what Lua scripts are for, see [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/EVAL) command.

Here a Lua script to get you started:

```
local len = redis.call('LLEN', KEYS[1])
if len >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
  local res = {n=len}
  for i=1,len do
    res[i] = redis.call('LPOP', KEYS[1])
  end
  return res
else
  return false
end
```

Use as

```
EVAL "local len = redis.call('LLEN', KEYS[1]) \n if len >= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then \n   local res = {n=len} \n   for i=1,len do \n     res[i] = redis.call('LPOP', KEYS[1]) \n   end \n   return res \n else \n   return false \n end" 1 list 3
```

This will only pop `ARGV[1]` elements (the number after the key name) from the list if the list has at least that many elements.

Lua scripts are ran atomically, so there is no race condition between reading clients.

As OP pointed in comments, there is risk of data-loss, say because power failure between `LPOP`s and the script return. You can use [`RPOPLPUSH`](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) instead of `LPOP`, storing the elements on a temporary list. Then you also need some tracking, deleting, and recovery logic. Note **your client could also die**, leaving some elements unprocessed.

You may want to take a look at [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). This data structure is ideal for distributing load among many clients. When using it with Consumer Groups, it has a *pending entries list* (PEL), that acts as that temporary list.

Clients then do a [`XACK`](https://redis.io/commands/xack) to remove elements from the PEL once processed. Then you are also protected from client failures.

Redis Streams are very useful to solve the complex problem you are trying to solve. You may want to do the [free course](https://university.redislabs.com/courses/ru202/) about this.

Comment: Amazing. This was exactly what I was looking for. You said Lua scripts are ran atomically. Can it actually fail during the execution & data is partially lost? e.g. With your example, when n=3, if the redis instance shuts down (e.g. power loss) when it is calling `LPOP` for the second time (out of total 3 calls needed), I assume data can be lost?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **prefetcher**.

Instead of each consumer greedily picking an item from the queue which leads to the problem of 'water water everywhere, but not a drop to drink', you could have a prefetcher that builds a **packet** of size = 6. When the prefetcher has a full packet, it can place the item in a separate packet queue (another redis key with list of packets) and pop the items from the main queue in a single transaction. Essentially, what you wrote:

> If there is only 1 Consumer client, the client can simply run LLEN
> command to check if the list contains at least N items, and subtract N
> using LPOP/RPOP.

If the prefetcher doesn't have a full packet, it does nothing and keeps waiting for the main queue size to reach 6.

On the **consumer** side, they will just query the prefetched packets queue and pop the top packet and go. It is always 1 pre-built packet (size=6 items). If there are no packets available, they wait.

On the **producer** side, no changes are required. They can keep inserting into the main queue.

BTW, there can be more than one prefetcher task running concurrently and they can synchronize access to the main queue between themselves.

### Implementing a scalable prefetcher

Prefetcher implementation could be described using a buffet table analogy. Think of the main queue as a restaurant buffet table where guests can pick up their food and leave. Etiquette demands that the guests follow a queue system and wait for their turn. Prefetchers also would follow something analogous. Here's the algorithm:

```
Algorithm Prefetch
Begin
   while true
      check = main queue has 6 items or more    // this is a queue read. no locks required
      if(check == true)
         obtain an exclusive lock on the main queue
         if lock successful
            begin a transaction
            create a packet and fill it with top 6 items from 
              the queue after popping them
            add the packet to the prefetch queue

            if packet added to prefetch queue successfully
              commit the transaction
            else
              rollback the transaction
            end if

            release the lock
            
         else
            // someone else has the excl lock, we should just wait
            sleep for xx millisecs
         end if
      end if
   end while

End
```

I am just showing an infinite polling loop here for simplicity. But this could be implemented using pub/sub pattern through [Redis Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications). So, the prefetcher just waits for a notification that the main queue key is receiving an LPUSH and then executes the logic inside the `while` loop body above.

There are other ways you could do this. But this should give you some ideas.

Comment: What I am asking is details of `there can be more than one prefetcher task running concurrently and they can synchronize access to the main queue between themselves.`. Because prefetcher that you described is similar to `consumers` that I described in the original question.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'll add it to the response.

Comment: Hello. I read your updated answer. Thank you, and I appreciate you looking into this, but updated answer still looks more like a bird-eye view of my question. I was specifically looking for Redis example utilizing available Redis commands. e.g. Your example consists of general pseudocode, which is just what I described in the question.

Comment: Also, polling/Redis Notification is not really relevant to the question, as I am not asking how consumers should accept/initiate requests. Not to mention Redis doesn't have 'rollback' type of commands that I know of, but you still mentioned in the pseudocode. I am just saying this as your answer seems to be off the point.

Comment: @user482594 - I know Redis doesnt have rollback. If you look at the pseudo code, the block between the begin transaction and the commit transaction is a MULTI - EXEC transaction block. If it takes the rollback transaction path, it would be a MULTI - DISCARD. Still atomic. I understand you would have preferred code, but my thinking mode is algorithmic. In any case, the accepted answer is great and meets the need.